# How to make shadow visible always in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, shadow

I am trying to make app bar with shadow below but when i scroll down my age it shown partially.How I can fix it?

Following is my code:-

my main.xml:

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainToolbar">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="1"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/customTabStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBlack" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<!--    Shadow for maintab-->

<View
    android:id="@+id/shadow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_for_maintab"/>
```

shadow_for_maintab.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
android:startColor="#1F000000"
android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

below are screen shots:

Default changes:-

[image: Default Changes]

When I scrolled it down

[image: When I scrolled it down]

Comment: both screen shots are same?

Comment: @Wini Sorry, my fault. Can you check it now!

Comment: share full code of my main.xml: